# Listview-item animation that starts on different items at random

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I'm trying to make a "disappear" animation for my listview-items.

I have two animations, one is a Doubleanimation which animates the opacity from 1 to 0 and the other one is a Thicknessanimation which animates the margin from 0,0,0,0 to 50,0,0,0.

If I set it to the Stackpanel's style (which is in the Listview.Itemtemplate) they all animate at the same time, and that looks kind of boring. So I want to make each object start the animation at random times.
Is there a good way of doing this in WPF?

The animation is triggered by a Datatrigger.

Comment: Post relevant XAML code.

Comment: Not random but this should set a delay <Storyboard  BeginTime="0:0:8"

Comment: Personally I just throw a FluidMoveBehavior on the ItemsPanelTemplate instead.

Answer (score 1):

To implement that correctly, you'll need to implement a custom `Panel` to do it. If you've not done this before, it's not so difficult and definitely something that all WPF developers should do when the need arises. You can find lots of information and a code example in the [Custom Panel Elements section of the Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Panels_custom_panel_elements) page on MSDN. Also see the [How to create a Custom Layout Panel in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html) article on WPF Tutorial.net

So that will give you an idea on how to create a custom `Panel`... you basically just implement the two `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` methods, in which you get access to the elements in the related collection control. I have several of these animated `Panel`s and I can animate each child's `Opacity` from the `ArrangeOverride` method like this:

```
private void AnimateOpacity(UIElement child, double from, double to, 
    TimeSpan animationDuration, EventHandler animationCompletedHandler)
{
    DoubleAnimation opacityAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(from, to, animationDuration,
        FillBehavior.HoldEnd);
    if (animationCompletedHandler != null) opacityAnimation.Completed += 
        animationCompletedHandler;
    child.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, opacityAnimation, 
        HandoffBehavior.Compose);
}
```